# How to make Django 2.0 to use Oracle 11g syntax instead of 12c?

Tags: django, oracle11g

This is my dev environment:

- Windows 7 (x64)
- Python 3.6.3 64bit (virtual environment)
- Django 2.0
- cx_Oracle 6.1
- Oracle 11.2 Enterprise Edition 64 bit (on remote machine)

I am failing to `migrate` (django *manage.py migrate*) because Django is creating sql suitable for Oracle 12c; but I am using 11g.

For example, django tries to execute this:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN identity_column = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM user_tab_cols
WHERE table_name = 'DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE' AND
column_name = 'NAME';
('DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE', 'NAME'); 
args=['DJANGO_CONTENT_TYPE', 'NAME']
```

But the column `identity_column` is not available on oracle 11g.

How can I make django use 11g syntax?

EDIT:

Tracing back the exception I found this in `..\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\oracle\schema.py`(method `_is_identity_column`, line 151):

```
cursor.execute("""
                SELECT
                    CASE WHEN identity_column = 'YES' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
                FROM user_tab_cols
                WHERE table_name = %s AND
                      column_name = %s
            """, [self.normalize_name(table_name), self.normalize_name(column_name)])
```

So the syntax is hard coded. Does this mean Django 2.0 is for Oracle 12c an onwards?

Comment: I don't know. Just being curious: what errors do you get? I'd expect vast majority of SQL statements to work on both releases.

Comment: @Littlefoot I have posted a sample sql.

Comment: Can you comment that code? As you've said, there's no IDENTITY_COLUMN in 11g's USER_TAB_COLS. Or, perhaps, "hardcode" it to return 0 (as there's no identity column in 11g either, it was introduced in 12c). Such as "SELECT 0 FROM USER_TAB_COLS WHERE ..."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [release notes of django 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#dropped-support-for-oracle-11-2) (with my emphasis):

> The end of upstream support for Oracle 11.2 is Dec. 2020. Django 1.11
>   will be supported until April 2020 which almost reaches this date.
>   **Django 2.0 officially supports Oracle 12.1+**.

So, for support of any other version of Oracle, you should downgrade to 1.11

Comment: Oops! I missed that. Thanks!