# Django migrate error for Oracle database table

Tags: python, django, oracle11g

I have created django project where following versions I have used.
Python version 3.8.6
Django version  3.1.2
Oracle 11g
I have run makemigrations which works all correct but migrate command gives me error i.e django.db.migrations.exceptions.MigrationSchemaMissing: Unable to create the django_migrations tabel (ORA-02000: missing ALWAYS keyword)

Database setting is following:

```
DATABASE = { 'default':{ 'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.oracle',
'NAME': '10.1.5.87:1529/cdxlive', 'USER': 'cisadm',  'PASSWORD':
 'cistechnology' } }
```

Table I am creating is

```
class Test(models.Model):
name = models.CharField()
score = models.CharField()
```

Answer (score 0):

`Oracle 11` is no longer supported by Django since version 2 [Django drop Oracle 11 support](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#dropped-support-for-oracle-11-2)

This StackOverflow answer has a possible solution for your problem

[Configure Django with oracle 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49229664/configure-the-django-with-oracle-11g-data-base-issue/49726448)

Comment: It says I have to install Django 1.11 but it is no longer supported.  And also I have downgraded python to 2.7 and after runnibg pip install django version 1.11 or  pip install django version 1.11.29 it givea error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement version (from version : 0.1.0, 0.1.1), No matching distribution  found for version==given version