# ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier error using INSPECTDB DJANGO

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models, inspectdb

I have an existing database in `Oracle 11.2`.

I am trying to use `inspectdb` utility of `django` to automatically create the models but I am getting the error:

```
ORA-00904: "IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
```

There is no column named `IDENTITY_COLUMN` in any of the tables and since I am not directly accessing the database, the chances of misspelling a column name or accessing a wrong column is not possible.

It would be very helpful if someone can give a direction as to what to fix to solve this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem also working with Oracle 11.2

I downgraded Django===2.1 to Django===1.11.13 temporarily to run inspectdb as a work around since my legacy models needed to be manually cleaned up anyway, but it was a good place to start for reverse engineering models from a legacy db.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me . First downgrade your django into a lower version (1.11.22) and run

```
python manage.py inspectdb > your_app_name/models.py
```

Then upgrade to whatever version you are using . I was using 3.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it is possible.

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb) don't mention `Oracle`:

> **inspectdb** works with `PostgreSQL`, `MySQL` and `SQLite`.

But a user said they got it working, for example [this comment in a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179469/is-it-possible-to-generate-django-models-from-the-database#comment1001793_1179481). See also [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914775/django-inspectdb-issue-using-oracle-database) for some hints.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-inspectdb explicitly mentions how oracle db behaves, so probably this is supported. But I realized that django 2.2 doesn't support Oracle DB version 11. That can be the issue