# How to inspect oracle database without primary key in django

Tags: python, django, oracle, django-models

command:

```
python .\manage.py inspectdb --database=ORACLE > models.py
```

This command run successfully.

But models.py output is

```
# Unable to inspect table 'acc_advance_other_adj_dt'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "USER_TAB_COLS"."IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
# Unable to inspect table 'acc_ari_entries_dt'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "USER_TAB_COLS"."IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
# Unable to inspect table 'acc_asset_mt'
# The error was: ORA-00904: "USER_TAB_COLS"."IDENTITY_COLUMN": invalid identifier
```

Comment: What version of django are you using?  InspectDB has a long history of not working with Oracle.  Also what version of Oracle is the database running?  There was this question from 4 years ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51598599/ora-00904-identity-column-invalid-identifier-error-using-inspectdb-django/60887463#60887463

Comment: cx-Oracle==8.3.0        
Django==4.0.8       
mssql-django==1.1.3         
pyodbc==4.0.34